# Angular - Issue in moving service into separate file

Tags: angularjs

I have a service with a few methods:

```
function userService($http, API, auth) {
   ....
}
```

and then used in my module like:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
   .service('user', userService)
   ...
```

All of this is in my app.js file, I want to separate things so its easier to maintain. I'm trying to use the line `.service('user', '/services/userService')` but its not working any ideas how to i need to reference this?

Thanks.

Comment: isn't that should be `require('/services/userService')`?

Comment: I tried that at he top of the app.js file. doesn't work

Comment: I meant to say `.service('user', '/services/userService')` should be `require('/services/userService')`

Comment: But then at what point would the keyword 'user' be set?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating a new module instead of use yours.

To retrieve an existing module and use it in a separated file, you have to do :

```
var app = angular.module('app')
    .service('user', userService')
    // ...
```

Instead of

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .service('user', userService')
    // ...
```

Documentation available at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval

**EDIT from @koox00 answer**

Don't forgot to load all files related to your module in your markup, in the good order (before load the file containing your module declaration).